# Run Roslyn analyzers from a program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

**Background of the requirement :**

We build api libraries ( for .Net, Java, C/C++ and Python ) for our customers, upon which they build their applications.  As and when we update our api libraries our customers face the challenge of finding changes required in their source to be able to use the new api libraries. Hence, we are planning to build a reporting tool that can run on their source and tell them precisely what changes they need to do in their code.

**Problem**

For now focusing on .Net only, the easiest way i could think of is to use built-in Roslyn Analyzers. The idea is to change the project references to the new api libraries, and then run the analyzers on the solution.

The problem where i got stuck that MSBuild command line has no option to just run analyzers ( skipping the build ). Then i tried of calling the analyzers using code ( which is also preferable ), for that i've added the nuget package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers , Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp. But i couldn't get any information on how to use the analyzers using these packages.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to run Rosyln-Analyzers from code ?
2. If yes, how to ? ( a sample code is much appreciated )

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to one of two things:

- Write analyzers which can auto fix the code to use the new API.
- Write a stand alone analysis tool which produces the report.

The analyzers you can deliver with the new nuget package for your new version, and then users can just go through all analyzer warnings and fix them. you don't need to run them, they will get run when the user starts working on the solution.

The stand alone tool the users can run to produce a report. If you want a report, then you want to do this and not write an analyzer

I found [this series of blog posts](https://joshvarty.com/learn-roslyn-now/) useful for learning about analyzers

Comment: I don't think i should write an analyzer, as the rules already exists in Rosyln analysers. For e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061 , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1501 , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0618. I wish to use these rules to validate the source.

Comment: you just want to treat warnings as errors for those numbers. See [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSWarningsAsErrors.aspx)

Comment: 2 of those are compiler errors, if they compile, then they will get errors to fix... I don't think they are roslyn code analyzers, they are just compiler warnings. I still think you want to write a standalone staic analysis tool, which they run against their solution, looking for the methods that no longer exist, and advising them of how they can fix those

Comment: i understand that those are compiler warnings / errors. But VS shows them without even building, that's what i am looking for. Any hints on how that can be achieved ?

Comment: I think you can do that with a stand alone tool. just load the project using roslyn, then compile and get the errors...

Comment: The source code is pretty big and that's the reason i don't really want to compile it. VS points the deprecated / obsolete calls instantly after opening the project / making the change ( Without build ). I wish to be able to replicate that, rather than building as the later will take a long time to build.

Comment: I believe that VS is still building the project, just in memory, using roslyn, not producing any build artifacts, which is why its quicker. I would look at something like [this](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/compiling-c-sharp-code-into-memory-and-executing-it-with-roslyn) as a starting point as a way to get the compilation errors without doing a full MSBuild